# How to get list of users in Box using api

Tags: api, box

is it possible to get the list of users in Box using api calls?
 i'm currently using "https://api.box.com/2.0/users" to get all users but what i  want to achieve is that i want to get list of users filtered by date created? is  there any way how to do that?

here's a sample screenshot for api call using postman[image: box api]

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of users filtered by date created using the [Enterprise Events endpoint](https://docs.box.com/reference#get-events-in-an-enterprise).

When you query the Enterprise Events endpoint, you can filter for specific event types using the event_type parameter. The API event name for new user creation is "NEW_USER". The created_after and created_before parameters let you specify a time range for the events needed.